# Git - Synchronize and overwrite files from Bitbucket to remote server

Tags: git

I'm trying to synchronize a branch from Bitbucket to the same branch on the remote server machine. And to do this ignoring some files and directories.

Now I try to explain me better. What I have done until now is to push the stable versions of my nodejs-app, from my local machine to Bitbucket. This works fine. Now I have the same branches as in local, and each one is a version of the app. I already pushed the files adding the file `.gitingore` at the root. So in Bitbucket there are the versions for every brunches.

What I would like to do is synchronize the file no the remote server from Bitbucket.
So the first time, when on the remote server there was nothing, I used the command clone

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:<my_username>/<my_repo>.git -b <my_bitbucket_branch> path/to/server/dir
```

After have done this, I updated from local to Bitbucket some files in a new branch called `my_bitbucket_branch`.

The question is: **what's the procedure to update/synchronize (and overwrite) the a specific `my_server_branch` with another specific `my_bitbucket_branch`, ignoring some dir/files?**

At the end I would like to switch versions of the (online/remote) nodejs-app simply switch branch, like this

```
git checkout v01
git checkout v02
...
```

I'm new to Git, hope it's clear.

**ADD**

I need something which update+override the branch not on the Bitbucket, not on my local-pc, but on my remote server (where there is the website in nodejs). I saw the "pull" command... maybe that?

If I had on Bitbucket a branch called "v02" and on the remote server a branch called "v01", I want to override v01 with v02. So all the file in v01(on remote server) will be exactly equals in v02(on Bitbucket).

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this procedure :
 `git add .`
`git commit -am "Some changes in BRANCH NAME"` 
 `git push origin <BRANCH NAME>`

By following these lines of code your specific branch at remote repo will be synchronized with your current code.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain enough what I would like to do :)
I used push to put from my local branch (on my pc) to the Bitbucket branch.
I need something which override the branch not on the Bitbucket, not on my local-pc, but on my remote server (where there is the website in nodejs). I saw the "pull" command... maybe that?

Comment: Pull is used to fetch the code from remote branch to local branch. Sorry to say but I'm lil bit confused about what you actually want? Can you please ask to the point?

Comment: Ok, I try another time. What's the procedure to update/synchronize (and overwrite) a specific my_branch (in local or another machine who has this branch) FROM a specific my_branch (on Bitbucket)? How do I set it to ignore some directories and files?

Comment: use command **git pull origin <BRANCH_NAME>** at the specific local branch to overwrite the specific code. If there is some warning or problem use **git stash** before to redo the changes of the local branch.